# Did Nebula know what would happen?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

So there are two teams in *Avengers: Endgame*: Natasha (Black Widow) and Clint (Hawkeye)/Nebula and War Machine.

Yet Black Widow and Hawkeye were chosen for the mission to Vormir. So did Nebula know to send them since one loved one had to be sacrificed and she gathered that they both share a history or was it just a normal team separation?

Comment: It appeared to me to be the expected normal teams, Nat and Hawkeye are best friends and have worked together for years. Makes sense to send them together regardless of the Soul Stone complication.

Comment: I dont think it was Nebula who made the choice of who would pair up for each team.

Comment: yeah, it would have been a bit of a waste of time if Nebula landed in Vormir with Clint ..

Answer (score 29, accepted):

She didn't know.

She only knew that Gamora knew where the stone was, was taken there by Thanos to help obtain it, and didn't come back - she didn't know the conditions under which the soul stone could be obtained (and neither did Thanos, and he thinks he knows everything).

Comment: Even then they still had to think *why* he killed her. 'Cos she fought back? 'Cos she kept lying? Dude'd got 2 stones, trying to defy him even at that point is impossible. I don't know but the most logical conclusion is that "he killed her, he got the stone, so someone probably has to die to get the stone, so we'd better think through what we're gonna do instead of waiting for a red skull face to show up and tell us."

Answer (score -2):

**Yes**, she knew! As they leave for Vormir, Nebula says "as long as they don't fall out".

Comment: I think she was just expressing disdain?

Comment: She was saying as long as they don't physically fall out of the ship, they will get to their destination.

Comment: @PeterL pretty sure it's a double meaning by the writers. Dramatic irony.

Comment: @OrangeDog If it's a double meaning then it's only on the meta level, i.e. nothing that Nebula knows. But it would also not be a well-placed word play anyway, as they don't really have a fall out. On the contrary. It would be well placed if the soul stone would mentally influence them to maliciously fight each other for it or s.th. like that. But yeah it could be a weak reference to one of them dying by falling in the end. Something Nebula definitely didn't know, so meta level at best.

Comment: @FrankHopkins it's not foreshadowing that they will fall out. Indeed, neither do they physically fall out of the ship. It means exactly what it says - they will succeed as long as they don't fall out. They must neither fall out of the ship, nor fall out with each other. The only question is whether Nebular knows the second stipulation, or whether it's only for the audience's benefit.

Comment: @OrangeDog well they do fall down a cliff. I'd rather see a connection there than with respect to the falling out with each other, as falling out with each other isn't really what happens or what the soul stone's thing is. And in either case, we have no indication that Nebula knows, so if it was meant at either foreshadowing their fall from the cliff or their "having to decide who goes" it was only between the writers and the audience, with Nebula being the medium only in that respect)

Comment: @FrankHopkins then you have misunderstood how writing works, or the soul stone, or both. The sacrifice has to be of something you love. Therefore if they had a falling-out, they would have nothing available to sacrifice.

Comment: @OrangeDog great, that even supports my argument that it doesn't make sense as foreshadowing regarding having a falling-out.

Comment: @FrankHopkins nobody is claiming what you are arguing against. You have just misunderstood it.

Comment: @OrangeDog ah, but then it doesn't make sense as well. She says "They will be fine, as long as they don't fall out". But they aren't exactly fine. I would be with you if she said "They will succeed, ..."

Answer (score -4):

I think she knew.. She said when they fight Thanos at Titan,

He took her to Vormir
He came back with the Soul Stone
She didn't

Comment: Welcome to Movies. Please substantiate your answer with a source. If this was meant to be a comment then remove the answer and add it as a comment.

Comment: She knew Gamora *died* on Vormir, but there's absolutely no indication she knew Gamora was *sacrificed*.