# Why did they not know that a soul was needed for the Soul Stone?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Engame*, Nat and Clint were the ones assigned to get the Soul Stone. However, they seem to not know how to get the Soul Stone and even get to the point where Clint doubted what the Red Skull said.

How did they not know?

Because Nebula was with them and she was there when Thanos went to Titan. She was even the one who concluded and told Quill, indirectly, that Thanos probably sacrificed Gamora in exchange for the Soul Stone, or at least that's how I understood it based on their conversation in the previous movie.

Did I miss something here? Or did I just misinterpret something?

Comment: Related, possible dupe: [Did Nebula know what would happen?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/99682/63559) - the answer theorizes she didn't

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Or did I just misinterpret something?

### What was said is certainly open to interpretation.

From *Infinity War* -

> Nebula: "He took her to Vormir. He came back with the Soul Stone... but she didn't."

and in *Endgame* -

> Nebula: "A dominion of death, at the very center of Celestial existence. **It's where... Thanos murdered my sister.**

So granted Nebula knows that Thanos and Gamora both went to Vormir and only Thanos came back *and* that he killed Gamora in the process of obtaining the Soul Stone but there's no **specific confirmation or indication that Nebula knew there was a direct correation between the two.**

She wasn't there to hear the Red Skull detail how it worked, she just realised that Thanos had killed her sister while getting the Stone.

Answer (score -3):

Nebula knew, but just didn't tell them, maybe because she thought if they knew beforehand they wouldn't go through with it, or it wouldn't work.

After Hawkeye and Black Widow leave Nebula and War Machine on Morag, she says to Rhodes that they (Natasha and Clint), will be fine "as long as they don't fall out with each other on the way" (or words to that effect).

Comment: The quote you are referring to is kind of a direct contradiction to what your answer claims - at the least it doesn't support it at all. Her comment in that scene mainly refers to them flying the spaceship they "borrowed" from Rocket. As they never flew (that / any kind of) spaceship before and Rocket seems to be quite attached to it, she says it's on auto-pilot and they will reach their goal (be fine flight-wise) if they don't fall out (of the ship). It's a joking reference to it being their first flight. It's never indicated she knows one has to die. If she knew she's hidden it completely.

Comment: That's one interpretation (although how one would "fall out" of a spaceship, an enclosed craft is a question this raises).
I interpreted as "fall out" referring to them arguing, breaking their bond of friendship, and therefore their love for each other and the sacrifice being in vain. Hence *fall out with each other*.
That version of Nebula knows about Thanos sacrificing Gamora. She knows it's a *soul for the Soul Stone*. She absolutely knows that one of them has to die.

Comment: That's imho the only in-universe explanation. Out of universe it could be seen as a word play indicating what will happen, but we have no indication that she knew, see also https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/99682/did-nebula-know-what-would-happen And the falling out is in-universe obviously meant as a joke which is also not that uncommon with cars or other "closed crafts" in the real world.