# Were Avengers aware of sacrifice needed for soul stone?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers Endgame* we see that Natasha and Hawkeye were tasked to get the soul stone. After events of *Avengers Infinity War*, especially after events on Titan, everyone knows that soul stone needs sacrifice if it were to be taken from Vormir.

So the question is when Natasha and Hawkeye were sent for it, did they already know about sacrifice thing? If they knew, why they fought for sacrificing themselves in vormir and not planned who will die earlier?

Comment: Closely related, possibly duplicate: https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/99682/46980

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Actually, they didn't.

All they knew about the location of Soul Stone which was on the planet Vormir. 
Avengers came to know about this from Nebula who wasn't aware of the sacrifice rule and only knew the location. In the Infinity War, only Thanos and Red Skull knew about the sacrifice thing.

> especially after events on Titan, everyone knows that soul stone needs sacrifice if it were to be taken from Vormir.

They only know that Gamora and Thanos went to Vormir and Thanos made it back, not Gamora. They were not aware of the sacrifice rule.

> **Nebula:** He took her to Vormir. He came back with the Soul Stone. But she didn't.

When Hawkeye and Black Widow come to Vormir, Red Skull told them about the rule and they think about whether it's true or not.